# Is there a way to find out the total number of bytes actually written on each node per second in a Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra, thrift, cassandra-3.0

I see bytes being written on commit log is in  MB's but the data that is being sent was actually couple of MBs(< 4 MB). Not sure why am I seeing such stats?

Here are dstats o/p of my disk(commitlog)

```
date/time   |usr sys idl wai hiq siq| 1m   5m  15m | read  writ| read  writ|util| recv  send
23-03 12:08:06| 27   4  66   2   0   0|13.8 6.14 3.50|   0   110M|   0   893 |66.8|  73M   79M
23-03 12:08:07| 29   5  64   2   0   0|13.8 6.14 3.50|   0   119M|   0   970 |58.8|  84M   81M
23-03 12:08:08| 29   4  64   3   0   0|13.8 6.14 3.50|   0   114M|   0   925 |70.4|  76M   75M
23-03 12:08:09| 30   6  63   2   0   0|13.2 6.13 3.52|   0   104M|   0   852 |58.0|  84M   73M
23-03 12:08:10| 30   5  63   2   0   0|13.2 6.13 3.52|   0   147M|   0  1190 |62.4|  92M   93M
23-03 12:08:11| 30   4  64   2   0   0|13.2 6.13 3.52|   0   113M|   0   923 |61.6|  77M   74M
23-03 12:08:12| 26   4  67   2   0   0|13.2 6.13 3.52|   0   134M|   0  1094 |56.0|  94M   90M
23-03 12:08:13| 39   5  54   1   0   0|13.2 6.13 3.52|   0   121M|   0   986 |54.4|  98M   88M
23-03 12:08:14| 25   4  68   3   0   0|12.7 6.15 3.53|   0   121M|   0   979 |71.2|  99M   87M
23-03 12:08:15| 36   6  55   3   0   0|12.7 6.15 3.53|   0   123M|   0   993 |62.0|  90M   93M
23-03 12:08:16| 31   6  60   2   0   0|12.7 6.15 3.53|   0   106M|   0   854 |54.8|  98M  104M
23-03 12:08:17| 37   6  54   2   0   1|12.7 6.15 3.53|   0   133M|   0  1067 |59.2|  92M   93M
23-03 12:08:18| 27   4  66   3   0   0|12.7 6.15 3.53|   0   116M|   0   936 |64.8|  97M   96M
23-03 12:08:19| 33   6  59   2   0   0|
```

Comment: looking for just commit log, or also from compactions and flushes?

Comment: I'm actually checking both as commit log is writing 100+ MB/s  +  Monitoring traffic on each node using dstat tool and i see lot of data being transfered between nodes.